# Consider defining a bean of type 'service.CloudVendorService' in your configuration error is showing

Tags: intellij-idea, javabeans

Consider defining a bean of type 'service.CloudVendorService' in your configuration.
This error is showing.

My project can be found here:
https://github.com/binit1212/rest-demo

There are several layers, so some annotation must be missing.

I have a controller, model, repository, implementation, and service layer.

1. This my controller:

   package com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.controller;

   import com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.model.CloudVendor;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
   import service.CloudVendorService;

   import java.util.List;

   @RequestMapping("/cloudvendor")
   @RestController

   public class CloudVendorController {
   CloudVendorService cloudVendorService;
   public CloudVendorController(CloudVendorService cloudVendorService) {
   this.cloudVendorService = cloudVendorService;
   }

   ```
   @GetMapping("{vendorId}")
   public CloudVendor getCloudVendorDetails(@PathVariable("vendorId") String vendorId){
       return cloudVendorService.getCloudVendor(vendorId);

   }

   @GetMapping()
   public List<CloudVendor> getAllCloudVendorDetails(){
       return cloudVendorService.getAllCloudVendors();

   }
   @PostMapping
   public String createCloudVendorDetails(@RequestBody CloudVendor cloudVendor)
   {
       cloudVendorService.createCloudVendor(cloudVendor);
       return "Cloud Vendor created successfully";
   }
   @PutMapping
   public String updateCloudVendorDetails(@RequestBody CloudVendor cloudVendor)
   {
       cloudVendorService.updateCloudVendor(cloudVendor);
       return "Cloud Vendor updated successfully";
   }

   @DeleteMapping("/{vendorId}")
   public String deleteCloudVendorDetails(@PathVariable("vendorId") String vendorId)
   {
       cloudVendorService.deleteCloudVendor(vendorId);
       return "Cloud Vendor Deleted successfully";
   }
   ```

   }
2. This is model class

   package com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.model;

   import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
   import jakarta.persistence.Id;
   import jakarta.persistence.Table;

   @Entity
   @Table(name="cloud_vendor_info")
   public class CloudVendor {
   @Id
   public String getVendorId() {
   return vendorId;
   }

   ```
   public void setVendorId(String vendorId) {
       this.vendorId = vendorId;
   }

   public String getVendorName() {
       return vendorName;
   }

   public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
       this.vendorName = vendorName;
   }

   public String getVendorAddress() {
       return vendorAddress;
   }

   public void setVendorAddress(String vendorAddress) {
       this.vendorAddress = vendorAddress;
   }

   public String getVendorPhoneNumber() {
       return vendorPhoneNumber;
   }

   public void setVendorPhoneNumber(String vendorPhoneNumber) {
       this.vendorPhoneNumber = vendorPhoneNumber;
   }

   private String vendorId;
   private String vendorName;
   private String vendorAddress;
   private String vendorPhoneNumber;

   public CloudVendor() {
   }



   public CloudVendor(String vendorId, String vendorName, String vendorAddress, String vendorPhoneNumber) {
       this.vendorId = vendorId;
       this.vendorName = vendorName;
       this.vendorAddress = vendorAddress;
       this.vendorPhoneNumber = vendorPhoneNumber;
   }
   ```

   }
3. This is my repository:

   package com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.repository;

   import com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.model.CloudVendor;
   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

   public interface CloudVendorRepository extends JpaRepository<CloudVendor, String> {

   }
4. This is my package impl;

   import com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.model.CloudVendor;
   import com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.repository.CloudVendorRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
   import service.CloudVendorService;

   import java.util.List;

   @Service
   public class CloudVendorServiceImpl implements CloudVendorService {

   ```
   CloudVendorRepository cloudVendorRepository;
   public CloudVendorServiceImpl(CloudVendorRepository cloudVendorRepository) {
       this.cloudVendorRepository = cloudVendorRepository;
   }



   @Override
   public String createCloudVendor(CloudVendor cloudVendor) {
       cloudVendorRepository.save(cloudVendor);
       return "Success";
   }

   @Override
   public String updateCloudVendor(CloudVendor cloudVendor) {
       cloudVendorRepository.save(cloudVendor);
       return "Success";
   }

   @Override
   public String deleteCloudVendor(String cloudVendorId) {
       cloudVendorRepository.deleteById(cloudVendorId);
       return "Success";
   }

   @Override
   public CloudVendor getCloudVendor(String cloudVendorId) {
       return cloudVendorRepository.findById(cloudVendorId).get();
   }

   @Override
   public List<CloudVendor> getAllCloudVendors() {
       return cloudVendorRepository.findAll();
   }
   ```

   }
5. This is service layer:

   ```
   package service;

   import com.thinkconstructive.restdemo.model.CloudVendor;

   import java.util.List;

   public interface CloudVendorService {
       public String createCloudVendor(CloudVendor cloudVendor);
       public String updateCloudVendor(CloudVendor cloudVendor);
       public String deleteCloudVendor(String cloudVendorId);
       public CloudVendor getCloudVendor(String cloudVendorId);
       public List<CloudVendor> getAllCloudVendors();
   }
   ```